# Adding horizontal spacer to CSS design

Tags: css

Hello and thank you,

I've seen a lot on horizontal spacers, but specifically, I am trying to put a padding space between the main body text and the left menu bar of [this site](http://audiobookreviews.com).

Adding margin-left or padding does not seem to work. On desktop it looks great, but on mobile, the text never resizes to "fulls screen" length.

Any help would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: I can open that page up and add padding to the text to make space.

Comment: I would suggest that you should use grids in this case. It's especially made to split the content of a div into blocks, either vertically or horizontally and can be quickly changed for mobile devices from 2 blocks to one blocks. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: What you really should do is have a sidebar div and a main content div that are both are floated. All content that should be shown in the right side would be in the main content div. Then you give the divs right/left margins

Comment: Perhaps post the relevant code instead of linking to the site.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Paulie_D, I was going to include a screen grab but thought that would just make more questions for people, then I would need to add the code snippit, but am unsure even what part of the page to include, sorry for my bad question though I will try and revise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like everything is fixed-width... from your sidebar to your >200px margins. Generally this is frowned upon because it causes tons of issues with smaller devices, and as @Tanckom suggested, you should probably look into restructuring the page with CSS grids.

This means that, without a major overhaul of the style sheet and structure, there's no quick and dirty solution that will make this page look good on mobile.

Here are a few steps you could take to chip away at a more responsive page design:

1. Add the following meta tag in your `<head>`:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```

   This will allow you to make the page width take the full width of the viewing device.
2. Look into [CSS Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) as alternative methods of structuring your page. These carry the benefits of staying away from large fixed numbers (such as margins of over 200px), and are more easily manipulated when the screen size changes.
3. Look into [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), and see how you could use them to change your site's styling depending on screen size. One such media query might look like:

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
       #sidebar_container {
           width:100%; /* or something like that */
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I obviously am a beginner and answers like yours are incredible, thank you!